# What does getting an answer from dig but not from whois imply?

Tags: networking, whois, dig

So when I execute this:

```
dig hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com
```

I get this:

```
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.122
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.123
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.124
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.125
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.126
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.127
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.22
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.120
hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com. 7208 IN  A   71.74.56.121
```

However when I execute this:

```
whois hrndva-omtalb.mail.rr.com
```

I get this:

```
No match for "HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM"
```

What conclusion can I draw from this?  Usually if I get a response from dig, I also get one from whois.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

> whois rr.com

dig will work on subdomains, whois will not.

Answer (score -2):

The conclusion I draw from it is that you don't know what you're doing with *whois*.

Whois is a tool for querying registries - not doing DNS lookups.

You should be able to do a *whois* lookup on *rr.com* because that is a *domain name*.  It is stored at the *.com* registry.  HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM is a *host* name.  You could use the *host* or the *nslookup* command to query it.

```
$ host HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.126
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.127
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.22
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.120
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.121
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.122
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.123
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.124
HRNDVA-OMTALB.MAIL.RR.COM has address 71.74.56.125
```

Comment: Exactly, was just answering this, but you got it all, so deleting mine. The main point is that they are completely different types of queries that parse the input based on different criteria. The input supplied to dig was valid, but the input supplied to whois was not.

Comment: kind of an arrogant answer ....

Comment: ... yet one which fits the question perfectly.

Comment: Stupidity by the power company has meant I have missed the first episode of the new Dr Who, so if you'll excuse me I'm not exactly in the best of tempers right now.

Comment: well shouldn't take it out on people who are trying to learn ....